# SAS Given a start & end date I need to know the dates of each 30 day period AFTER the first 35 days

Tags: date, datetime, sas, date-range, days

I am am given 2 dates, a start date and an end date.

I would like to know the date of the first 35 day period, then each subsequent 30 day period.

I have;

```
start       end
22-Jun-15   22-Oct-15
9-Jan-15    15-May-15
```

I want;

```
start       end         tik1        tik2        tik3        tik4
22-Jun-15   22-Oct-15   27-Jul-15   26-Aug-15   25-Sep-15   
9-Jan-15    15-May-15   13-Feb-15   15-Mar-15   14-Apr-15   14-May-15
```

I am fine with the dates calculations but my real issue is creating a variable and incrementing its name. I decided to include my whole problem because I thought it might be easier to explain in its context.

Comment: What is your own current approach to the problem?

Comment: you can have a macro for getting the values of the columns also incrementing variable name in the loop.... create a temp table with the variables you got....and merge with previous tabel

Comment: Do you really want the wide output format? Or would a long and narrow format work also, i.e, generating one record for each period,

Comment: I can't think of any other way to present this information so I expect I need it wide as shown. This step is currently done manually because I never know how many tik columns I will need to create. These examples are basic and I expect I could just create tik1-tik(x), populate the required columns and delete the rest. The more elegant approach would be to create only the columns I need as I go rather than pick a large enough number x and drop the columns to the right when I find the last populated tik(x) column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem via following logic:

1) Determining number of columns to be added.

2) Calculating the values for the columns basis the requirement

```
data test;
input start end;
informat start date9. end date9.;
format start date9. end date9.;
datalines;
22-Jun-15 22-Oct-15
09-Jan-15 15-May-15
;
run;

/*******Determining number of columns*******/
data noc_cal;
set test;
no_of_col = floor((end-start)/30);
run;
proc sql;
select max(no_of_col) into: number_of_columns from noc_cal;
run;

/*******Making an array where 1st iteration(tik1) is increased by 35days whereas others are incremented by 30days*******/
data test1;
set test;
array tik tik1-tik%sysfunc(COMPRESS(&number_of_columns.));
format tik: date9.;
tik1 = intnx('DAYS',START,35);
do i= 2 to %sysfunc(COMPRESS(&number_of_columns.));
tik[i]= intnx('DAYS',tik[i-1],30);
if tik[i] > end then tik[i]=.;
end; 
drop i;
run;
```

Alternate Way (incase you dont want to use proc sql)

```
data test;
input start end;
informat start date9. end date9.;
format start date9. end date9.;
datalines;
22-Jun-15 22-Oct-15
09-Jan-15 15-May-15
;
run;

/*******Determining number of columns*******/
data noc_cal;
set test;
no_of_col = floor((end-start)/30);
run;

proc sort data=noc_cal;
by no_of_col;
run;

data _null_;
set noc_cal;
by no_of_col;
if last.no_of_col;
call symputx('number_of_columns',no_of_col);
run;

/*******Making an array where 1st iteration(tik1) is increased by 35days whereas others are incremented by 30days*******/
data test1;
set test;
array tik tik1-tik%sysfunc(COMPRESS(&number_of_columns.));
format tik: date9.;
tik1 = intnx('DAYS',START,35);
do i= 2 to %sysfunc(COMPRESS(&number_of_columns.));
tik[i]= intnx('DAYS',tik[i-1],30);
if tik[i] > end then tik[i]=.;
end; 
drop i;
run;
```

**My output:**

```
> **start   |end        |tik1     | tik2     |tik3     |tik4**
> 22Jun2015 |22Oct2015  |27Jul2015| 26Aug2015|25Sep2015|    
> 09Jan2015 |15May2015  |13Feb2015| 15Mar2015|14Apr2015|14May2015
```

Comment: I need more time to digest this! The output is as required, I prefer not to  use proc sql  but then again I can appreciate the brevity in this case. I will definitely expand my mind going through this. Thanks!

Comment: @heroz If you don't want to use proc sql, I have added an alternate solution for that. Let me know if you need a detailed description of the code. Also, if my answer helped you solve your query please visit the link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: That looks great, a detailed description would be very helpful. The code that I am most interested in is the final section where you use the %sysfunc to increment the variable name, that will go into my code to complete it.

Comment: **number_of_column** stores the value of number of columns that needs to be created for the desired output ("4" in this case).  **array tik tik1-tik%sysfunc(COMPRESS(&number_of_columns.));** creates an array of columns from tik1-tik4(in this case) . **&number_of_columns.** calls the value "4", **compress** is to remove spaces (if any) while storing the value of number of columns and since compress function is not listed in macro dictionary so to use compress function we need **%sysfunc**

Comment: Great, I'm reading up on %sysfunc, I have seen an example when used with compress. Unsure why the compress is needed in this case however? &number_of_columns is only ever a small number.

Comment: What do you mean by "&number_of_columns is only ever a small number" ? And compress is just a precautionary step for removing spaces if any.

Comment: I was just curious why there was a need to use compress. The number of columns would never exceed 100 (in in reality I would only expect it is possible to need 15 maximum unless my rules changed) but that is only 3 digits in the number, so why would the compress be used? I am assuming the compress is used as a catch all but in reality could a space ever happen? Just wanted to know your reasoning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer long vertical structures.  I would approach it like:

```
data want;
  set have;
  tik=start+35;
  do while(tik<=end);
    output;
    tik=tik+30;
  end;
  format tik mmddyy10.;
run;
```

If you really need it wide, you could transpose that dataset in a second step.

Comment: I would not have thought of it this way but it is certainly worth a exploring further because this looks straight forward. Wide is preference due to the way this information is being used, I will look into transpose - I am learning all the time. Thanks for supplying this!

Comment: I would like to mark this as useful but I can't do it because I have a low rep, sorry about that.